# Reading a text file into a text box using nsdialog? NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS scripting installer. I need to create a TextBox with Multiline support, in Custom page. Need to read a text file and set the text content to TextBox. Please find my code block below:

```
StrCpy $3 ""
FileOpen $4 "C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Installer\License.txt" r
loop:
FileRead $4 $1

StrCpy $3 "$3$1" ; append the line and copy it to another variable
IfErrors +1 loop   
FileClose $4

${NSD_SetText} $ctrlTextBox "$3"
```

The above code able to read only 8119 characters only, but my file contains 30,000+ characters.

Please help me to read the large file and set the content to TextBox.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can fill a textbox with a little bit of text at the time (inside your loop) if you use [EM_SETSEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (twice) to move the caret to the end and then use [EM_REPLACESEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to append text.

If you can use a rich edit box instead then use some code I wrote a long time ago, you can find the forum thread [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=288129)...

Edit:

As long as the textbox is empty when you begin you don't have to deal with the caret:

```
function custcreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

nsDialogs::CreateControl ${__NSD_Text_CLASS} ${__NSD_Text_STYLE}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_READONLY} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 0 0 100% 50u ""
Pop $0

FileOpen $4 ${__FILE__}" r
loop:
    FileRead $4 $1
    SendMessage $0 ${EM_REPLACESEL} 0 "STR:$1"
    IfErrors +1 loop
FileClose $4

nsDialogs::Show
functionend
```

Comment: TextBox has some limitations - length of text. I suggest to use Rich Edit Box. Also NSIS variables have limited size - I think it is 1024 characters.

Comment: You have EM_LIMITTEXT to extend the textbox total limit. 1024 is the default variable size in the ANSI version but he might be using a different version...

Comment: Thanks Anders,

Rich Edit control solved my problem

; === TextBox1 (type: TextMultiline) ===
  nsDialogs::CreateControl RichEdit20A ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${WS_VSCROLL}|${ES_READONLY}|${ES_MULTILINE}|${ES_WANTRETURN} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 8 120 440 104 "" 
  Pop $txtLicenseControl
  nsRichEdit::Load $txtLicenseControl "C:\Users\Surya\Desktop\Installer\License.txt"